# How can i convert images to pdf in java servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, pdf, itext

I have some problem with conversion image to pdf file.

I done single image to pdf conversion, now i want to convert multiple images into a single pdf file.

I am using itext library for creating the pdf.

This is my code for create single pdf with only one image.

```
  Document convertJpgToPdf=new Document();
        //Create PdfWriter for Document to hold physical file
        PdfWriter.getInstance(convertJpgToPdf, new     FileOutputStream("D:\\PDF_Path\\ConvertImagetoPDF.pdf"));
        convertJpgToPdf.open();
        // Write Somethinf into that File
        convertJpgToPdf.add(new Paragraph("Welcome, Your Input Image is Converted to PDF, Save the File"));
        convertJpgToPdf.add(new Paragraph("PDF Produced by Converting Image to PDF as Servlet"));      
        //Get the input image to Convert to PDF
        Image convertJpg=Image.getInstance(uploadPath);
        //Add image to Document
        convertJpgToPdf.add(convertJpg);
        //Close Document
        convertJpgToPdf.close();
```

My problem was i have one folder, that folder contains 10 images, how can i convert that all images into a single pdf file,

like

```
       PDF File Header

       image1

       image2

       ..........
       ..........

       imageN
```

Is it possible. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer this : http://bigsnowball.com/content/create-multi-page-pdf-scanned-fax-images-java-using-itext

Answer (score 3):

```
Document document = new Document();
    // step 2
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
    // step 3
    document.open();
    // step 4
    // Adding a series of images
    Image img;
    for (int i = 0; i < RESOURCES.length; i++) {
        img = Image.getInstance(String.format("resources/img/%s", RESOURCES[i]));
        if (img.getScaledWidth() > 300 || img.getScaledHeight() > 300) {
            img.scaleToFit(300, 300);
        }
        document.add(new Paragraph(
                String.format("%s is an image of type %s", RESOURCES[i], img.getClass().getName())));
        document.add(img);
    }
```

Please read tutorial of itext its working fine
[click here](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=183)

Comment: +1 for "read the manual" which is the only true answer to this thread, but you're very friendly to provide copy/paste-able code.

Comment: In this link directly give the images, but i want to open the folder for get that images, and i am using servlet